# Redis Pub/Sub causes web socket connection to hang

Tags: ruby, websocket, redis, sinatra

I'm building a web application that connects to a server via web sockets. The server component is a small Ruby application based on `sinatra`, `redis`, and `faye-websocket`. The server is running on Phusion Passenger. A separate updater daemon is constantly pulling updates from various sources and publishes them to redis (using the `redis` gem and `Redis::publish`).

In order to push the updates to the clients I tried the following in my Sinatra app:

```ruby
get '/' do
  if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(request.env)
    store = Redis.new
    ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(request.env)

    ws.on(:open) do |event|
      store.incr('connection_count')
      puts 'Client connected (connection count: %s)' % store.get('connection_count')
    end

    ws.on(:close) do |event|
      store.decr('connection_count')
      puts 'Client disconnected (connection count: %s)' % store.get('connection_count')
    end

    ws.rack_response

    store.subscribe(:updates) do |on|
      on.message do |ch, payload|
        puts "Got update"
        ws.send(payload) if payload
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works only partially. A client can connect successfully and also receives updates but the `store.incr` and `store.decr` calls don't work. Also, the connections don't seem to be closed correctly—when I fire up multiple clients, I noticed that the connections pile up and the Passenger server stops working eventually.

Log output:

```
devserver_1 | App 614 stdout: Got update
devserver_1 | App 614 stdout: Got update
devserver_1 | App 614 stdout: Got update
```

When I comment out the following block, keeping track of the connections suddenly works:

```ruby
store.subscribe(:updates) do |on|
  on.message do |ch, payload|
    puts "Got update"
    ws.send(payload) if payload
  end
end
```

Log output:

```
devserver_1 | App 1028 stdout: Client connected (connection count: 1)
devserver_1 | App 1039 stdout: Client connected (connection count: 2)
devserver_1 | App 1039 stdout: Client disconnected (connection count: 1)
devserver_1 | App 1028 stdout: Client disconnected (connection count: 0)
```

So using `Redis::subscribe` seems to somehow interfere with the web socket connection.

How can I solve this?

- Phusion Passenger version 4.0.58
- ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
- sinatra (1.4.6)
- faye-websocket (0.9.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is that Faye uses EventMachine which means there's a reactor on your thread that is handling events, and calling your callbacks `ws.on(:open)` and `ws.on(:close)`.

Now when you hit

```
store.subscribe(:updates) do |on|
  on.message do |ch, payload|
    puts "Got update"
    ws.send(payload) if payload
  end
end
```

This is a blocking operation - it entirely blocks the current thread. If your current thread is blocked, the reactor can't listen for events and then call your callbacks.

One solution to this is to run your `store.subscribe` on a different thread so it doesn't matter if it blocks that thread.

But I think a better solution is to use a [non-blocking version of the Redis library:](https://github.com/mloughran/em-hiredis)

From the documentation:

```
redis = EM::Hiredis.connect
pubsub = redis.pubsub

pubsub.subscribe(:updates).callback do
    puts "Got update"
    ws.send(payload) if payload
end
```

Both of these (Redis + Faye) should register with the EventMachine reactor loop, so that it dispatches events to both.

Comment: I should point out that the Redis guidelines state that you should not use the same connection for both publishing and subscribing. so `store` should be split into `store` for publishing and data and `store_sub` for subscribing.